# Can I disable udisk2.service to reduce boot time on my Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04

Here is an output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.   
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @22.413s
└─udisks2.service @14.245s +8.166s
  └─basic.target @13.822s
    └─sockets.target @13.820s
      └─uuidd.socket @13.817s
        └─sysinit.target @13.176s
          └─systemd-timesyncd.service @12.401s +772ms
            └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @11.581s +770ms
              └─local-fs.target @11.546s
                └─boot-efi.mount @11.459s +86ms
                  └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-507A\x2d2B05.service @11.238s +158ms
                    └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-507A\x2d2B05.device @11.236s
```

Also adding output of `systemd-analyze blame`

```
8.166s udisks2.service                                      
7.102s accounts-daemon.service                              
6.851s dev-sda2.device                                      
5.069s NetworkManager.service                               
4.319s switcheroo-control.service                           
4.298s systemd-logind.service                               
4.287s wpa_supplicant.service                               
2.695s gpu-manager.service                                  
2.662s grub-common.service                                  
2.602s rsyslog.service                                      
2.433s fwupd.service                                        
2.207s systemd-resolved.service                             
1.954s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
1.853s grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
1.804s upower.service                                       
1.800s secureboot-db.service                                
1.574s gdm.service                                          
1.566s apparmor.service                                     
1.259s keyboard-setup.service                               
1.242s kerneloops.service                                   
1.141s networking.service                                   
1.065s systemd-udevd.service                                
 973ms systemd-sysusers.service                             
 926ms polkit.service                                       
 925ms colord.service                                       
 901ms swapfile.swap                                        
 867ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
 789ms systemd-modules-load.service                         
 772ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
 770ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
 691ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
 677ms systemd-sysctl.service                               
 629ms systemd-random-seed.service                          
 599ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
 483ms user@1000.service
```

Can you help me in guiding what services I can disable safely.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with single boot.

**Update 2**

```
  cat /etc/fstab  

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b9113027-0606-4c19-9705-9df918cc858b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       0
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=507A-2B05  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile
```

```
  sudo blkid :
  /dev/sda2: UUID="b9113027-0606-4c19-9705-9df918cc858b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="652de5b4-beff-453f-b695-612578b781b1"
  /dev/sda1: UUID="507A-2B05" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="210b47a1-b7a5-4f99-a266-23aee6b19eb7"
```

```
free -h 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.7Gi       2.7Gi       156Mi       329Mi       883Mi       473Mi
Swap:         2.0Gi        65Mi       1.9Gi
```

Also screenshot of SMART test :
[image: SMART Test]
[image: SMART Test 2]

Also `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` shows nothing.

`grep -i sda /var/log/syslog* :`https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5stQZqPSGB/

```
grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile    none       swap    sw      0       0
```

Comment: Rather than butcher your system, try and find out why it's taking long to boot. And, how long is long, in your case? You may have a HDD/SDD problem. Can you manually `fsck` your Linux partition(s), and also show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` SMART Data & Tests, SMART Data window? And `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `free -h`.

Comment: @heynnema i have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but you didn't provide the `cat /etc/fstab`, or tell me how long it takes to boot. Also, the SMART Data window is scrollable, and I need a 2nd screenshot to see the missing values. Also show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`. Your swap is too small, and you're getting read/seek errors on your disk.

Comment: @heynnema I dont know anything about swap partition. Can you tell me what is optimal size. Also do i need to replace my HDD?

Comment: Too early to say. Still gathering info. You didn't type the `grep` command correctly. Please redo. Also show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` (and if this output is large, paste it at https://paste.ubuntu.com). How old is this disk/computer?

Comment: Your original paste of `cat /etc/fstab` was cut short, but the `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` showed me the missing stuff. I still need to hear how long it takes to boot, and how old this computer/disk is. I'm still not finding what I'm looking for in syslog, so it's probably best to post the entire `cat /var/log/syslog` at https://paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: @heynnema It is taking around 37 secs to boot. I think this HDD is around 4 years old. And for that entire syslog, it is 8 MB file. Should i paste it at paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: 37 seconds if really OK, for a computer with only 4G RAM and 2G swap. What processor do you have? I'm still trying to determine if there's a disk problem or not, so go ahead and post /var/log/syslog to https://paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: It is unable to paste. it is showing error as Bad Gateway. If you think that boot up time is ok then ok. I just thought maybe i could bring it further down.

Comment: Its a Pentium Processor. And no i dont have any Startup Applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**boot time**

With a Pentium processor, and 4G RAM, and 2G swap, and probably an older HDD, and Ubuntu 20.04, don't expect boot times less than 60-90 seconds. If you want a quicker system, consider using Xubuntu instead.

**system services**

First, the way to reduce boot time is not to disable critical system services. So... re-enable all services that you stopped/disabled.

**swap & RAM**

With only 4G RAM, a 2G swap is too small. It also looks like you could use more RAM. Add RAM in matched pairs so that the system can take the speed advantage of memory interleaving. So, if you have one 4G RAM stick now, either add a second 4G RAM stick, or replace the one 4G RAM stick with two 8G RAM sticks.

Let increase your swap from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**disk**

Your disk is getting read/seek/reallocation errors, but in reviewing snippets of /var/log/syslog, I haven't been able to discern what the problem might be. Your HDD may be failing, but I can't prove it right now. Keep good backups.

Comment: Thanks for this. For now i will check with increasing swap and report back to you.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r Did the larger swap file help at all?

Comment: I have increased the swap size but not yet rebooted. Will let you know once i do it.

Comment: Thanks @heynnema. The increase in the swap file size helped to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it looks like this on Lubuntu 20.04:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
1min 30.015s nmbd.service                                                                             
      7.411s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
      1.832s dev-sda1.device                                                                          
      1.234s systemd-logind.service                                                                   
      1.191s systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
      1.073s apt-daily-upgrade.service                                                                
       974ms upower.service                                                                           
       838ms motd-news.service                                                                        
       824ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                
       734ms systemd-journald.service                                                                 
       715ms networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
       642ms accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
       599ms snapd.service                                                                            
       597ms udisks2.service                                                                          
       525ms fwupd-refresh.service                                                                    
       454ms fwupd.service                                                                            
       343ms avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
       331ms NetworkManager.service                                                                   
       305ms dundee.service                                                                           
       299ms polkit.service                                                                           
       275ms apport.service                 

$ man udisks

NAME
       udisks - Disk Manager

DESCRIPTION
       udisks provides interfaces to enumerate and perform operations on disks and storage devices. Any application (including unprivileged ones) can access the udisksd(8) daemon via
       the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus[1]. In addition to the D-Bus API, a library, libudisks2 is also provided. This library can be used from C/C++ and any
       high-level language with GObjectIntrospection[2] support such as Javascript and Python. udisks is only indirectly involved in what devices and objects are shown in the user
       interface.
```

And it seems that nothing positive could not be expected in case of udisks service disabling. So better make sure your drives are mounted correctly and accessible from your user's session.

Use also `journalctl -b | grep udisks` to see what could happen during OS boot so it takes so much time to load.

To find out which services are essential and which are not, use:

```
ps aux | grep servicename
```

For example:

```
$ ps aux | grep udisks
root         809  0.0  0.1 395468 15492 ?        Ssl  11:17   0:03 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
spacer      1338  0.0  0.1 393924 12020 ?        Ssl  11:18   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
root        7842  0.1  0.0  13916  4552 ?        Ss   14:31   0:03 /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sdb5 /media/spacer/SUPER -o rw,nodev,nosuid,windows_names,uid=1000,gid=1001,uhelper=udisks2
root        9153  0.0  0.0  12148  2704 ?        Ss   14:57   0:00 /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sdc1 /media/spacer/Passport -o rw,nodev,nosuid,windows_names,uid=1000,gid=1001,uhelper=udisks2
```

Then `man servicename` to see what it does.

Then use the next command to see what services are dependent of the service you desire to disable:

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies udisks2 --all --reverse
udisks2.service
● └─graphical.target
```

In this case `graphical.target` could suffer. However, you could try to stop it and look at what will happen (but it could not be safe):

```
$ sudo systemctl stop udisks2
```

Comment: Can i disable some other services which are not required at boot?

Comment: If they are not required for proper OS functioning you can, but other services are not so big resource consuming ones to disable them as it looks like from your commands outputs. What drive type do you have? SSD or HDD?

Comment: Actually i dont know which services are required for proper functioning and which are not.And i have disabled few services from other online articles to bring down the list to this. I am using HDD.

Comment: Here's the article : https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/clu0lj/short_guide_to_improve_slow_boot_on_ubuntu_1804/

Comment: Thats why i am hesitant to disable any service before confirming for any bad after effects.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r re: "*And i have disabled few services from other online articles to bring down the list to this*"... re-enable any services that you disabled/stopped. Hope you remember which ones you did.

Comment: @heynnema i have written every service i disabled in a file. But re enabling them might take the boot time higher again.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r please answer my last questions in my comment above.